# Cant find debug toolbar in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

using latest version of vs code, i cant see the debug toolbar.
Version: 1.66.2

i've tried changing it in the settings from floating to docked to hidden and back to floating, restarted the program and i still cant see it.

Answer (score 2):

My debug tool bar disappeared even though the "Run and Debug" option inside the context menu of Run and Debug was checked:

[image]

The solution is to go Visual Studio Code settings and find `Debug` inside `Features` section:

[image]

Then find `Debug: Tool Bar Location` setting: mine was set to `floating`. After I've changed its value to `docked` I can see toolbar again:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think ive sorted it. the toolbar only appears if debugging is in process. it disappears when it has stopped. I thought it stayed there all the time.

Answer (score 0):

For whoever still struggles with the problem, the problem for me was that the "Run and Debug" menu was unchecked for some reason.
Right-click on the menu bar and check it.
[Right Click on Menu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1sAt.png)

Answer (score -2):

You should press this combination of key : CTRL+Shift+Y

Comment: that opens/closes the debug console. im looking for the toolbar that has symbols like a red sqaure, a green recycle, yellow flash for hot reload, restart.

Comment: Please take more care to answer exactly the question and not something similar.